# Hollywood horror movie, ghost of a twin maybe

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Okay so I don't remember much at all. There was a ghost in this movie which tortured the people living in a house. In the end we get to know that the ghost was of the woman's daughter who died in their basement. This girl was born ugly so her mother locked her in their basement and used to feed her there. One time they went on a trip and forgot to feed her and when they returned, she was dead.